# how to change the df column name in struct with colum value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

```
df.withColumn("storeInfo", struct($"store", struct($"inhand", $"storeQuantity")))
      .groupBy("sku").agg(collect_list("storeInfo").as("info"))
      .show(false)

+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|sku|info                                               |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{2222, {3, 34}}, {3333, {5, 45}}]                 |
|2  |[{4444, {5, 56}}, {5555, {6, 67}}, {6666, {7, 67}}]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

when I am sending it to couchbase

```
{
  "SKU": "1",
  "info": [
    {
      "col2": {
        "inhand": "3",
        "storeQuantity": "34"
      },
      "Store": "2222"
    },
    {
      "col2": {
        "inhand": "5",
        "storeQuantity": "45"
      },
      "Store": "3333"
    }}

]}
```

can we rename the col2 with the value to the value of store? I want it to look like something as below. So the key of every struct is the value of store value.

```
{
  "SKU": "1",
  "info": [
    {
      "2222": {
        "inhand": "3",
        "storeQuantity": "34"
      },
      "Store": "2222"
    },
    {
      "3333": {
        "inhand": "5",
        "storeQuantity": "45"
      },
      "Store": "3333"
    }}

]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, we can't construct a column as you want. two limitation:

1. The field name of `struct` type must be fixed, we can change 'col2' to another name (eg. 'fixedFieldName' in demo 1), but it can't be dynamic(similar to Java class field name)
2. The `key` of `map` type could be dynamic, but the `value` of `map` must be same type, see the exception in demo 2.

maybe you should change the schema, see the outputs of demo 1, 3

### demo 1

```
df.withColumn(
      "storeInfo", struct($"store", struct($"inhand", $"storeQuantity").as("fixedFieldName"))).
      groupBy("sku").agg(collect_list("storeInfo").as("info")).
      toJSON.show(false)
// output:
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|value                                                                                                                                                                                              |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|{"sku":1,"info":[{"store":2222,"fixedFieldName":{"inhand":3,"storeQuantity":34}},{"store":3333,"fixedFieldName":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":45}}]}                                                           |
//|{"sku":2,"info":[{"store":4444,"fixedFieldName":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":56}},{"store":5555,"fixedFieldName":{"inhand":6,"storeQuantity":67}},{"store":6666,"fixedFieldName":{"inhand":7,"storeQuantity":67}}]}|
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### demo 2

```
df.withColumn(
      "storeInfo",
      map($"store", struct($"inhand", $"storeQuantity"), lit("Store"), $"store")).
      groupBy("sku").agg(collect_list("storeInfo").as("info")).
    toJSON.show(false)
// output exception:
// The given values of function map should all be the same type, but they are [struct<inhand:int,storeQuantity:int>, int]
```

### demo 3

```
df.withColumn(
      "storeInfo",
      map($"store", struct($"inhand", $"storeQuantity"))).
      groupBy("sku").agg(collect_list("storeInfo").as("info")).
      toJSON.show(false)
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|value                                                                                                                                        |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|{"sku":1,"info":[{"2222":{"inhand":3,"storeQuantity":34}},{"3333":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":45}}]}                                         |
//|{"sku":2,"info":[{"4444":{"inhand":5,"storeQuantity":56}},{"5555":{"inhand":6,"storeQuantity":67}},{"6666":{"inhand":7,"storeQuantity":67}}]}|
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```